# Params is nil on entry into controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2
```

In my inventories_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
before_action :fetch_product, only: [:show]

def show
 ........
end

def fetch_product
  if params.has_key?(:sku)
    @product = Product.get_product(params)
  end
end
```

This works fine, when I do: http://0.0.0.0:3000/sku/12345678

I am trying to implement search functionality, so I modified nventories_controller.rb as follows:

```
def fetch_product
  if params.has_key?(:search) && !params[:search].blank?
    product = Product.find_by_sku(params[:search])
    if !product
      params = params.except[:search]
      redirect_to product_show_path, alert: 'Product was not found'
    end
    params = params.merge!(:sku, product.sku)
  end
  if params.has_key?(:sku)
    @product = Product.get_product(params)
  end
end
```

When I do: http://0.0.0.0:3000/sku/12345678

I get an instant error message:

```
undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Using my debugger, I find that on entry into the fetch_product method, params is nil

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`params = params.merge!(:sku, product.sku)` modifies the hash in place and returns nil, don't do that assignment, just call `params.merge!` (if you still want to do the assignment, remove the "!").

Personally, I wouldn't modify the params hash unless it's really really needed, I would use another variable.

Comment: What I'm missing though, is that params is nil, on entry into that method, before it gets to the merge point.

Comment: if it's nil before the action then check your before_actions if you have more, something is messing that up but you are not showing enough code